# "Усилял" — правильно ли это?

Tags: орфография, лексика, глаголы

В тексте встретилось: *алкоголь, как увеличительное стекло, **усилял** все его чувства.*

Режет глаз. Имеет ли такая форма этого глагола право на существование?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современном русском литературном языке нет такого глагола "усилять".
Есть глаголы [**уси́лить**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) (*что сделать?* сов. вид) и **уси́ливать** (*что делать?* несов. вид), которые являются видовой парой.
Так что правильно надо было написать "алкоголь, как увеличительное стекло, **усиливал** все его чувства".

[На всякий случай проверила по орфографическим словарям: 1938 г. и 1957 г. (110 тысяч слов). Слово "усилять" в них отсутствует.]

P. S. Стоит отметить, что глагол все-таки используется (нечасто, конечно), в том числе и классиками (но ведь мы-то с вами к этой "категории" не относимся).

*Крупной фигурой, густым голосом, и как он твёрдо ступал, и как уверенно принимал решения — Столыпин ещё **усилял** то впечатление крепости, несбиваемости, здоровья, какое улавливалось и через газеты...* ([А. И. Солженицын](https://books.google.ee/books?id=j4IBb4R7Iw8C&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB&source=bl&ots=C1PCSr9BUi&sig=ACfU3U3OCBs1vvakhbfIvVWA41dwIfFjKA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ28Kf9bbgAhW3wcQBHYB8ATM4ChDoATAEegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB&f=false))

*Так восхищения Духа прекрасны, но нужно следить, чтобы они не расслабляли, но **усиляли** энергию нашу* ([Е. И. Рерих](https://books.google.ee/books?id=HwNTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=21_uuW7wlQ&sig=ACfU3U2i3n7YPQahOW9N5xpS35eTvBJBng&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE4MP0iLfgAhUp0aYKHUItCcA4ChDoATABegQIBBAB#v=onepage&q=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B8&f=false)).

Comment: глагол такой есть и странно очень запрещать его использование, пусть он и является малоупотребимым https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C